# Parsing an irregularly spaced text file in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file that looks like :

```
Date     Fruit-type  Color         count
aug-6     apple  green         4
aug-7     pear  brown         5
aug-3     peach  yellow         10
aug-29     orange  orange         34
```

I would like to parse it to remove the irregular spaces into a nicely formatted pandas dataframe. I thought to remove the spaces and replace them with another delimiter but could not figure out the logic.

Desired output

```
Date,Fruit-type,Color,count
aug-6,apple,green,4
aug-7,pear,brown,5
aug-3,peach,yellow,10
aug-29,orange,orange,34
```

Comment: I tried using the split() method by aka fruit.split() but was unable to do it with a dataframe I was able to do it with a simple string though like 'aug-6     apple  green         4'

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] of your coding implementation to help better illustrate your implementation issues.

Comment: @user3609179 then isn't your problem solved? You just need to open the file and loop over each line calling `split` then `join` them back together with a comma separator. For a string `s` `','.join(s.split())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use command line tools, you can run this `awk` command to turn it from space delimited to comma delimited.

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++){printf "%s,", $i} print $NF}' data.txt
```

Otherwise, pandas can import space delimited files easily.

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_table('data.txt', sep='\s+')
```

With data.txt as:

```
Date     Fruit-type  Color         count
aug-6     apple  green         4
aug-7     pear  brown         5
aug-3     peach  yellow         10
aug-29     orange  orange         34
```

The output is

```
     Date Fruit-type   Color  count
0   aug-6      apple   green      4
1   aug-7       pear   brown      5
2   aug-3      peach  yellow     10
3  aug-29     orange  orange     34
```

You can read more here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files

Comment: how do I save the result generated with awk on my terminal in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, ",")}1' file

Date,Fruit-type,Color,count
aug-6,apple,green,4
aug-7,pear,brown,5
aug-3,peach,yellow,10
aug-29,orange,orange,34
```